# SQLAlchemy: Filter by objects in a member list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following classes,

```
class Person:
    id
    name
    jobs

class Job:
    name
    person
    person_id (FK)
```

where `Person.jobs` refers to class `Job` objects. Now I'd like to perform the following query,

```
# for a given person p
Job.query.filter(Job.notin_(p.jobs))
```

Is it possible in *SQLAlchemy*?

Please not that I do not want to write `Job.query.filter(Job.person_id != p.id)`.

Comment: Why not? It's exactly the thing you're looking for, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: are you talking about [`notin_` operator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.notin_)?

Comment: Have you even tried out this code before posting here?

Comment: @gonczor That's just a pesudocode.

Answer (score 1):

Nope !

As the documentation [about in_ explains](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_), as of version 1.2 of SQLAlchemy, you can not have list of instances of object, only :

- list of ID
- empty list
- select
- bound params

As of version 1.2, only what you describe as "do not want" is the right answer :

```
Job.query.filter(Job.id.notin_([j.id for j in person.jobs]))
```